# How a signal is generated by the brain when we want to move a body

Tags: neuroscience, cognitive-neuroscience, neurophysiology, neuroanatomy

I've read tons of articles about how moving our bodies is going on. BUT I've found some part of topic just IGNORED. ALL authors just pass the part "our brain generates the signal". I have been trying to find the answer for 1 week and found nothing.

Is it an unanswered question in neuroscience? Or they just skip because they don't know, or it is so trivial question and only I cannot understand it?

Because in order to depolarize the neuron it should open ion channels by our wish. E.g. I wanna move my leg up, just because I can. My brain opens ion channels just because I want it. My will should be like physical power isn't it?

Comment: Wanting to move, thinking about moving, all your wants and desires and motivations are all brain activity. You don't open ion channels because you want them open, you want things because ion channels opened.

Comment: @BryanKrause, okay. I moved leg up, I can move it, I can leave it, it is fully controlled process now. Someone else can tell me to move my leg. In case if all of them are already opened channels we wouldn't have control over them, isn't it?

Comment: I'm simplifying to the extreme. It's of course not only "channels opening" but activity in populations of cells that in turn influence other populations and themselves. The point is that you cannot separate your thoughts from your neural activity. They are the same thing.

Comment: @BryanKrause, sure, I didn't separate. I want to know, how abstract "desire" (will, or wish) can be converted to PHYSICAL power whatever it is: opening ion channels, generating transmitters, put these transmitters into some exact neurons.
Because I decide to move my arm, completely by my desire, it's not a reaction to any external things.

Okay, putting it in another manner: how abstract things are created without any input reasons?

Comment: And I'm telling you: those desires and abstract thoughts are not materially different from other types of neural activity evoked by a stimulus. The physical power comes when those signals are sent to muscles.

Comment: @BryanKrause, neural activity - it's a completely physical thing because it makes neuron depolarize which is physical phenomenon.

Back to your answer: what the stimuli are if I want to move my arm? or even more, If I start thinking about something because I want, no external affections, it's a fully controlled process by me. You can tell me that situations before lead to your question and lead to your moving, but know I can make my arm move, ca make it not to move, fully controlled in real-time, there is no determination.

Comment: I know I'm repeating myself a bit here but I don't think it's sinking in... You know when you think you are controlling something? That's brain activity. Physical processes in your brain. That's the stimulus. If you are even thinking about thinking about thinking a thought, that is physical brain activity.

Comment: @BryanKrause, it little shifts the question. Sorry, but then how the primary thought about thought and so furth has occurred. I mean special controlled thought about moving my arm? We any way end up with the moment when this desire or whatever be at the start. Anyway, it was triggered by me, anyway I can control it.

Comment: You are your brain. They aren't separate. Your thoughts, including desires to do something, is neural activity. They aren't separate.

Comment: @BryanKrause, I see it's clear, but how then desire, will or thought is generated? How they appeared?
It seems like recursion, but okay, how then the thought about moving arm has occurred? It cannot be caused by random other thoughts, because I can break it, by a desire not to moving. But this desire emerged somehow, how? that is the question about how primary exact neurons is fired?